# Resharper - Debug static method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, resharper

I have one project in a solution. Running that project is without any problem. I added a static method to test a database connection via Entity Framework. If i debug this static method with Resharper's debug, it crashes it cannot find a section with connection string in app.config. ( Other projects accessing app.config also fails )

I tried to copy app.config to output.
I tried to set "Use separate AppDomain".

What should i do ? Thanks !

Comment: You need to clarify your question and maybe provide some code. Resharper debug - do you mean the Resharper Debug Unit Tests? If so, have you added the connection string to the Unit Test project's app.config?

Comment: I have not created any unit test project. It's main project with static method and It crashes on creating db context as it cannot find section in app.config. ( seems like it cannot find a app.config )

Answer (score 0):

Is this using ReSharper's [Run Configurations](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/28/run-configurations-debug-any-static-method-in-visual-studio-and-more/)? If so, I'd say it sounds like a bug, where the host for running the static method doesn't set up the app.config correctly. I'd suggest [raising an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=).

Comment: Well, If i create a unit test project and copy my project app.config to unit test's folder, it's working fine. If i tried to debug my static method directly in my main project ( with correct app.config ) it fails because missing sections in app.config. Anyway, I raised an issue, let's see :)